# $T:x\to\phi_x$ is a linear isometry from $X$ into $C(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $\Omega := \{f \in X':||f||=1\}$. For each $x\in X$, let $\phi_x: \Omega \to \Bbb K$ be defined by $\phi_x(f)=f(x), f\in \Omega$.  Show that $\phi_x \in C(\Omega)$ for every $x\in X$ and the map $T:x\to\phi_x$ is a linear isometry from $X$ into $C(\Omega)$.

Need some hints for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Hahn-Banach Theorem we have that $$||x||=\sup\{|f(x)|:f \in X^*,||f|| \leq 1\}$$ for an arbitrary $x$ in a normed space $X$

> Thus $$||x||=\sup\{|f(x)|:f \in X^*,||f|| \leq 1\}=$$ $$\sup\{|\phi_x(f)|:||f|| \leqslant 1\}=||\phi_x||=\sup\{|\phi_x(f)|:||f||=1\}$$

I hope this helps.